# How to create list with 3- digit numbers which first digit + second digit = third digit

Tags: python, list, generator

I'm new to Python and been trying to solve this problem.
I want to create list of 3 - digit numbers in which `first digit + second digit = third digit` and if sum of first two digits is greater than 9 I want the third digit of that number to be second digit of the sum. eg. 583 where 5+8=13 so the last digit will be 3. I want to have 50 3-digit numbers like that
this is what I've got so far.

```
import random as rd

N=50

ar1 = [rd.randint(100, 999) for i in range(N)]
```

Comment: Judging by the answers, I don't think you've made the question very clear. It would help if you showed the result you are hoping for.

Comment: There is only 45 values where in `abc` you have `a!=0` and `a+b=c`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Attention

There is only **45** different 3-digits numbers `abc` you have `a!=0` and `a+b=c`.

The following solution  uses a **limit** fo tries to avoid infinite loop in case you ask too many

---

To generate one number that follows your rule, you need to generate 2 digits, then check if their sum is lower than 10 (to be one digit)

```
a, b = randrange(1, 10), randrange(10)
if a + b < 10:
    # you have the tuple (a, b, a + b)
```

Then use a loop to go until you reach your limit

```
def generate(N=50, tries=1000):
    result = set()
    while len(result) != N and tries > 0:
        tries -= 1
        a, b = randrange(1, 10), randrange(10)
        if a + b < 10:
            result.add(int("".join(map(str, (a, b, a + b)))))
    return result
```

You'll obtain a list

```
{257, 516, 134, 268, 909, 527, 145, 404, 279, 538, 156, 415, 549, 167, 808, 426, 303, 
 178, 819, 437, 314, 189, 448, 707, 325, 202, 459, 718, 336, 213, 729, 347, 606, 224, 
 101, 358, 617, 235, 112, 369, 628, 246, 505, 123, 639}
```

Comment: your explanation was very helpful but I want the result to be as numbers and not as sets

Comment: @ddnn5 read again at the top, there is only 45 different values

Comment: @ddnn5 Sidenote: they're tuples, not sets. Sets are unordered.

Comment: I think i'm not explaining well. result that you've got is what I was looking for. I just want them to be outputed as 3-digit numbers in a list

Comment: @ddnn5 that's what you have, you have not a list, but not a set, that's the same use, or just do `return list(result)` in the method

Comment: @ddnn5 If the answer satistifies you, you can [accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)